# Ways to find out all the dependent packages while offline installation

Tags: python, package

I want to install Python packages offline. When I download a `.whl` to my computer, it may depend on other packages, and so on, so on...

The question is, how do I know all the dependent packages that I need to download?
If I don't want to use annoconda.

Comment: When you say you want to install them offline what do you mean? If you're offline how would you download packages?

Comment: I download packages from pypi, then copy them to my computer which is offline.

Comment: If you use pip, you can install all your dependencies with `pip install`. Then run `pip freeze` and it will list all of the packages including all dependencies

Comment: That means I should install that online, and then export the dependencies.

Comment: You need to download them at some point, no?

Comment: That's right. The condition is that there isn't python or pip on the computer which is online(we call it PC-1), I want to install package-A on the computer which is offline(PC-2). I download A on PC-1 and install it on PC-2, it shows A need Package-B. Then I download B on PC-1 and install it on PC-2, still it shows B need Package-C, and so on. I want to know them before I install A on PC-2, so as to download all packages and easily install them.